# Is JDK8 compatible with Windows XP?

Tags: java, windows-xp, java-8

I found it is possible to install JDK8 on Windows XP (to avoid install error - we have to change `jdk-8u11-windows-i586.exe` file with some HEX editor (for example free XVI32) and change string `RegDeleteKeyExA` with `RegDeleteKeyA` filling zeros instead two last letters).

But I wonder if the JDK8 will work without further problems - I mean related to various `.dll` and other files of Windows XP?

Comment: I had the same issue today with a VM, my conclusion was no. When I googled the error code, I found a link to an oracle doc saying it wasnt supported (although it was a screen capture of the doc, not the actual doc, so I suppose it could have been faked :/). I just downloaded the java 7 installer and used 7 instead.

Comment: I don't believe anyone can give you a definitive answer beyond Oracle's notice of ***NON***-support of Windows XP.  You might be able to hack it to work but always run the risk that you will continue to turn up things that need to be patched, or that cannot be patched.  That way lies madness.  Don't bother.

Comment: See [The Future of Java on Windows XP](https://blogs.oracle.com/henrik/entry/the_future_of_java_on) (July 11, 2014) by Henrik Stahl, Oracle VP Product Management, Java Platforms. This is as official as it gets.

Answer (score 4):

[First link](https://www.java.com/en/download/faq/winxp.xml) on Google:

> Can I install Java 8 on Windows XP?
>
> Java 8 is not supported on Windows XP, and Windows XP users will be
>   unable to install Java 8 on their systems as there are known issues
>   with the installer on Windows XP that prevent it from installing
>   without manual intervention. If you are on Windows XP it is not clear
>   that it is worth updating to Java 8 without also updating the OS.

Comment: But it is possible to install it on Windows XP :) And very easy.

Comment: Installing it doesn't mean it's going to work correctly, especially over the long term.  How many bugs are you going to find that you have to hassle with?  How many are going to be unfixable?  It's just not worth it.

Comment: Let's wait for more answers - maybe some have longer experience.

Comment: Oracle has changed their stance. They now say it's not supported, but can indeed be used. The [first link](https://www.java.com/en/download/faq/winxp.xml) provided by @markspace has been updated.

Comment: @TravisChambers "Yes. As noted, users may still continue to use Java 8 on Windows XP at their own risk, but we can no longer provide complete guarantees for Java on Windows XP, since the OS is no longer being updated by Microsoft."  I wouldn't call that an improvement.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft doesn't support Windows XP, nor does Oracle.

> But it is possible to install it on Windows XP

You can install it but it may or may not work.  Even if it works, doesn't mean it is supported.